# I can't find an elegant way to add a Database Source to a dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid, dgrid

For now I have

```
require([
            "dojo/on", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid","dgrid/Tree","dgrid/Editor", "dgrid/Keyboard", "dojo/_base/declare",
            "dgrid/data/createHierarchicalStore", "data/projects_data",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(
            on, Grid, Tree, Editor, Keyboard, declare, createHierarchicalStore, hierarchicalCountryData
        ){
            var count = 0; // for incrementing edits from button under 1st grid

            function nbspFormatter(value){
                // returns "&nbsp;" for blank content, to prevent cell collapsing
                return value === undefined || value === "" ? "&nbsp;" : value;
            }

            var StandardGrid = declare([Grid, Keyboard, Editor, Tree]);

            window.grid = new StandardGrid({
                collection: createHierarchicalStore({ data: hierarchicalCountryData }, true),
                columns: [
                    {renderExpando: true, label: "Name", field:"variant_name", sortable: false, editor: "text", editOn: "dblclick"},
                    {label: "Visited", field: "bool", sortable: false, editor: "checkbox"},
                    {label:"Project", field:"project", sortable: false, editor: "text", editOn: "dblclick"},
                    {label:"locked", field:"locked", editor: "text", editOn: "dblclick"},
                    {label:"modified", field:"modified", editor: "text", editOn: "dblclick"},
                    {label:"summary", field:"summary", editor: "text", editOn: "dblclick"}
                ]
            }, "treeGrid2");

                grid.on("dgrid-datachange", function(evt){
                    console.log("data changed: ", evt.oldValue, " -> ", evt.value);
                    console.log("cell: ", evt.cell.row.id, evt.cell.column.field);
                });
                grid.on("dgrid-editor-show", function(evt){
                    console.log("show editOn editor: ", evt);
                });
                grid.on("dgrid-editor-hide", function(evt){
                    console.log("hide editOn editor: ", evt);
                });
        });
```

data/projects is a js file containing the data. but how to connect this dGrid now to a MySQL database? Can't find any good information in the docs. I think might be something with JSON rest but not sure about this.

Addition:
I can show the db in an HTML Table. is there a suitable possibilty to populate dGrid from a HTML Table?

I am still missing something. Have connections from
Database -> PHP
but can't get result in a proper JS to load into dStore.

Comment: this is very broad subject, can you tell us what other technologies you are using, and is your application going to be used in-house or for the public. is there authentication on this data or it is open for the public. or it will be called internally ? loads and loads of questions please be more specific.

Comment: the database is probably on the same server or at least a server inhouse. technology used...bower, html5, javascript, mysql. nothing special+

Comment: as i mentioned you need to be more specific, you can't do a query to your server in javascript without some service in the middle. are you using .net MVC, or php  in the middle or all your project based on client side ?

Comment: yes kind of a mvc and in the middle should be php...the missing link is how to get a json from php dgrid understands. I think

Comment: in best case it is doing it maybe with jquery ajax

Comment: I am not sure what is kind of MVC but if it is MVC then you can simply create an action inside the controller, this action will use methods in the model to get the data from mysql. using ajax you can send this action a get request, the response should be the data as string or json.

Comment: I found this http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/connecting-mysql-and-the-dojo-toolkit-mysql-data-store/ but it is not the elegant way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest path forward is to write a service in your server-side language of choice (sounds like PHP in this case) that produces JSON output based on the data in your MySQL database.  Depending on the potential size of your data, you can potentially design your data to work with one of two out-of-the-box stores in dstore: `Request` (and `Rest` if write operations are also involved), or `RequestMemory`.

The simpler of the two is `RequestMemory`, which simply combines the features of the `Memory` store with an up-front server request (via `Request`).  This store will expect the service to respond with one complete data payload: an array of objects where each object is a record in your database.  Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "foo": "baz"
    }
]
```

The `Rest` store expects data in the same format, *but* also expects the service to handle filtering, sorting, and ranges.  Filtering and sorting are represented via query string parameters (e.g. `foo=bar&baz=bim` in the simplest case for filter, and `sort(+foo)` or `sort(-foo)` for sort), while ranges are typically represented via the HTTP Range header (e.g. `Range: Items 0-9` for the first 10 items).

Implementing a service for the `Rest` store is obviously more work, but would be preferable if you're expecting your data source to potentially have thousands of items, since `RequestMemory` would have no choice but to request all of the items up-front.

With either of these stores, once you have a service that outputs JSON as appropriate, you can create an instance of the store with its `target` pointing to the service endpoint, then pass it to a grid via the `collection` property.

If your data is intended to represent a hierarchical structure, it should still be possible to mix `dstore/Tree` into `dstore/RequestMemory` or `dstore/Request`, provided that your hierarchy is represented via parent ID references.  By default, `Tree` filters children via a `parent` property on each item, and reports `mayHaveChildren` results by inspecting a `hasChildren` property on each item.